# MATLAB dsolve not working

Tags: matlab, dsolve

I'm solving the diffusion equation in MATLAB for a particular system, but there is a problem with the second solution I get, nsub(r). Ideally I want it to just be a function of r with two undetermined constants and while the first part of the expression is indeed some besselfunctions it also contains ,r, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true). Does anyone know how to solve this problem and what goes wrong? Here is my code:

```
clear all
clc

%%%%%% constants %%%%%%%
r_nw=50*10^(-9);
pitch_nw=500*10^(-9);
f_sub=10^18;
f_nw=10^18;
L_nw=100*10^(-6);

%%%%%% diffusion on wire %%%%%
tau_nw=1000*10^(-9);
D_nw=1*10^-9;
lambda_nw=sqrt(D_nw*tau_nw);

%%%%%% diffusion on substrate %%%%%%%
tau_sub=100*10^(-9);
D_sub=1*10^(-9);
lambda_sub=sqrt(D_sub*tau_sub);

%%%%%% diffusion equation on wire %%%%%%%%
syms nw(z)
nw = dsolve(D_nw*diff(nw,z,2) == -f_nw + nw/tau_nw,nw(L_nw)==0);
nw(z)=simplify(nw);
dnw = diff(nw,z);

%%%%%% diffusion equation on substrate %%%%%%
syms nsub(r)
nsub = dsolve(diff(nsub,r,2)+1/r*diff(nsub,r) == -f_sub + nsub/tau_sub);
dnsub = diff(nsub,r);
```

Comment: My first guess would be, that you have to define way more variables as symbolic ones using `syms`. At least the un-determined constants.

Comment: But then why does the solution work for the first differential equation but not the second? If you were right shouldn't they both give a bad solution?

Comment: The solution to the bessel function is dependent on r so those are parameters for how the bessel function will be solved when you give an r.

Comment: But if I try to evaluate nsub(5) for example, it will not give out a number as it should.

Comment: And it works for the other solution, so it seems there is something fundamentally wrong with solution it spits out for nsub.

Comment: I have discovered that the problem comes from r appearing explicitly in the differential equation. Like if you had y'(x) = x*y the x would cause a problem for dsolve. Does anyone know how to get around this?